# How to share variable in the views after firing event laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this listener class

```
class NotifyMR
{
/**
 * Create the event listener.
 */
public function __construct()
{

}

public function handle(LeaveRequestWasReviewed $event)
{
    return $event->leaveRequest.'->'.$event->statue;
}
}
```

so I need to share some variables in the views after firing event , so how to do it ?

Comment: Share in the view? Or just use in the event?

Comment: @Farkie yes share in the view

Comment: What fires this event?

Answer (score 0):

Via `View` facade

```
View::share('key', 'value');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this event is fired after post-dispatch